# postgreSQL login as created new user?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to postgresql database. I followed instruction online and get my postgreSQL database installed and everything works fine. with psql, I created new user user1 as below:

```
CREATE USER user1 WITH PASSWORD '123';
```

Now I have a user called 'user1', in addition to default user 'postgres'.

I'm very confused with what those user can do. I'm not sure what is the use of creating the new user.

My questions are:

- Can I log into the database as user1? How?
- Can the user see all the database in the system, no matter what the database owner is? In my case, all the database I created is owned by 'postgres'.
- Am I able to make the user see only some of the databases?

Comment: `psql -U user1`

Comment: Postgresql's Database Users documentation is excellent for this - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/user-manag.html

Comment: @Ryan when I type 'psql -U user1' , I got error message says' psql: FATAL: database user1 does not exist'.  I checked users with '\du', 'user1' is definitely there.

Comment: You’ll need to specify a database that exists with `-d`, too.

Comment: @Ryan  when I type 'psql -d db1 -U user1', it never asked for password. I got into the database directly, like '#db1=>'

Comment: then U connect over socket, add -h localhost to psql arguments

Comment: See the `\connect` command in the [psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)